# How often does GCP update the billing charges shown on GCP console? Is it real time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How often does Google cloud platform update (refresh) the billing charges shown on GCP console? Is there a fixed delay or is it real-time?

Comment: It's definitely not real time, but I'm not sure what the delay is.

Answer (score 1):

The billed charges are updated daily and the invoice is generated monthly. One can also check usage on demand  programmatically, follow the instrucions -> https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/11/monitor-and-manage-your-costs-with.html

Comment: This doesn't appear to have any beneficial impact on the time delay, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm also not sensing that this will give us on demand (real time) data .... in fact the article says "New billing data is exported automatically into the dataset as it becomes available-- usually multiple times per day. BigQuery billing export also contains a few new features to help you organize your data:" ... i.e. multiple times per day.