# BigQuery API: Query usage per day quota reached for unknown reasons

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm a user of bigquery and the last week I just keep hitting the `Query usage per day` for no apparent reason. According to the Quota page I have reached 17TiB, however according to the Billing page I am only billed for 9 TiB since yesterday. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnZS8.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8XEH.png) screenshot.

I've also set up billing export (saved in a table `cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_`) for my project and if I add up the processed bytes of all jobs since yesterday I only get to about 10TiB.

I have no idea where else to look for the reason I keep hitting this quota limit? So some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide better screenshots? The image is too small

Comment: I've edited my post with better screenshots @rmesteves

Answer (score 0):

The `Billing` doesn't seems to work in real-time as you can see in other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561248/how-often-does-gcp-update-the-billing-charges-shown-on-gcp-console-is-it-real-t).
I suggest that you wait a little to generate a new report and compare with the usage indicated in the quota.

If you need to increase your quota at the moment to keep everything working, you can do:

1. Go to `APIs & Services`
2. Find `BigQuery` API and click
3. Go to `Quotas` in the menu at the left of the screen
4. Edit the desired category's limit

Please, let me know later if the Billing still not matching the usage.
I hope it helps

Comment: Hi @rmesteves

I am still only billed for 12 TiB since 2019-01-13.

However while my quota this morning was 17TiB it reset around 08:00UTC and is now up to 5TiB again, so that is atleast 22TiB.

I am aware I can increase the quota. I have it now set to 17TiB but I don't want to get charged for 17TiB, so I would like to have it correspond to the actual amount I am billed such that I can decrease it again and not have to worry about actually being billed for 17TiB.

Comment: We should wait 24 hours to be sure about it. Please keep me updated

Comment: Did it changed?

Comment: 2019-01-13 I was billed 9.49TiB, 2019-01-14 I was billed 7.71 TiB. Again last night the quota was hit (17TiB). Still seems this quota counts some non-billed data, but can't figure out what exactly. @rmesteves

Comment: Try to create a new report for the last 3 days. Use goup by Product and in the products select BigQuery, BigQuery Data Transfer Service and BigQuery Storage API.  Please let me know the result

Comment: I don't have the products `BigQuery Data Transfer Service` and `BigQuery Storage API` available in this dropdown. Also I am not billed for these products.

Comment: Does the problem still happening?

Comment: If the problem still happening, I encourage you to contact the Cloud Billing Support https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/